# How can I get "year" "month" "date" from timestamp in pyarrow?

Tags: csv, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am trying to extract the "year" "month" "date" from the arrows timestamp[s] type. I know how to do it in pandas, as follows

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
dataset = ds.dataset(path, format="csv")
table = dataset.to_table()
## following codes wont work as table is arrow type and it doesn't have the map function.
table['date'] = table['time'].map(lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
table['year'], table['month'], table['day'] = table['time'].apply(lambda x: x.year),table['date'].apply(lambda x: x.month), table['date'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
```

Easiest option is to convert this arrow DataFrame to pandas and do this. But the file size I am dealing with is much big and dont want to take the additional cost of converting it into pandas. As the end goal is after getting the year, month and day I want to use those as partitions in writing as parquet.

Trying my best to avoid the intermediate conversion, to make it much efficient in converting csv files to parquet. Is this achievable with the current functionalities available within arrow ?

Comment: This functionality is not yet available in pyarrow, so for now your best option is to specifically convert this column to pandas and use the pandas methods.

Comment: I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-11759 to track an enhancement for adding such methods.

Comment: @joris Does this add lots of overhead while conversion ? I am trying to convert ~150 GB of file.

Comment: @joris can I convert just a column ?

Comment: Yes, you can select the column (as you did in your question above) and convert that to pandas with `to_pandas()`

Comment: @joris I am trying this. But its taking for ever, this is much smaller sample data ~ 100 Million rows. Is this expected ? Any better of doing this ?

Comment: That shouldn't take that long for 100 milliion rows, I think (assuming you have enough memory). Can you update your question with the code you are using?

Comment: @joris managed to make it work. We are experimenting on large scale implementation of arrow here and might be having more questions. I hope stack overflow is the best place to ask those. or is there any other portals to ask questions specific on arrow ?

Comment: For very specific question with reproducible code example StackOverflow is fine, but otherwise also feel free to reach out on the Arrow user mailing list (see https://arrow.apache.org/community/)